# Domain missing from response cookie in Chrome

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a reason that a cookie's domain would be excluded from a cookie, only in Chrome?

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 application hosted with IIS 8.5 that is using cookie authentication as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie). It works perfectly in Firefox (see image below), IE11 and Edge - returning the domain in the response and creating a cookie as expected. All subsequent authentication and passing of the cookie works as well in those browsers.

[image: Response cookie in Firefox]

However, in Chrome the `Domain` is missing from the cookie in the response (see image below). Subsequent requests do not attach the cookie and thus the server does not receive it and thinks the user must be authenticated.

[image: Response cookie in Chrome]

What is especially odd is that when I search the cookies in Chrome, I do find the cookie (see below).

[image: Cookie in Chrome]

I was originally using session expiration for the cookie, but as you can see in the screenshots above I changed it to use a date, but that had no impact on this issue.

In Startup.cs I have:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.None,
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
});
app.UseAuthentication();
```

In AuthenticationController.cs I have:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "cookie");

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties() {
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6),
        IsPersistent = true
    });
```

It may be worth noting that this application is being access via an iframe in the [Canvas](https://www.canvaslms.com/?lead_source_description=instructure.com_) Learning Management System.

Any help would be much appreciated.

### Update

I created a basic cookie in this context that was independent of the cookie authentication.

```
CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions();
options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
Response.Cookies.Append("TestCookie", "this is the cookie value", options);
```

The same issue occurred with the creation of that cookie, so it does not seem like this issue is specific to the cookie authentication mechanism.